# Twitter Bootstrap Form Wizard/Jquery.validate - prevent user from moving to next tab if form is not valid

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

So far, i tried following:

1. In `onNext` - first thing `if (!form.valid()) { return false; }` this still moved the user to following tab.
2. In `onNext` - first thing:

   if (!form.valid()) {

   $('.error').first().focus()

   return false;

   }

   still, the wizard moved to next tab.
3. `$('.button-next').click( function (e) {

   ```
     if (!form.valid()) {

       e.preventDefualt();

       return false;
      }

    return true;

   }`
   ```

and still no help.

How can I prevent the user from moving to another tab if the form is not valid so far?

Btw, the validation works ok - not valid fields are highlighted properly.

**Update - Code** *the onNext func*

```
onNext: function (tab, navigation, index) {
            console.log('in on next');

            if (!form.valid()) {
                console.log('not valid');
                $('.error').first().focus();
                return false;
            }

            var total = navigation.find('li').length;
            var current = index + 1;
            // set wizard title
            $('.step-title', form).text('Step ' + (index + 1) + ' of ' + total);
            // set done steps
            jQuery('li', form).removeClass("done");
            var li_list = navigation.find('li');
            for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                jQuery(li_list[i]).addClass("done");
            }

            if (current == 1) {
                form.find('.button-previous').hide();
            } else {
                form.find('.button-previous').show();
            }

            if (current >= total) {
                form.find('.button-next').hide();
                form.find('.button-submit').show();
            } else {
                form.find('.button-next').show();
                form.find('.button-submit').hide();
            }

            App.scrollTo($('.page-title'));
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

My goal: stop the wizard from transferring to the next tab if any field in current step is not valid. Allow the user to fix all invalid fields and only then move on to the next step.

I changed the `onNext` function to following:

```
onNext: function (tab, navigation, index) {
            console.log('in on next');

            var allowStep = form.valid();

            if (allowStep) {

                var total = navigation.find('li').length;
                var current = index + 1;
                // set wizard title
                $('.step-title', form).text('Step ' + (index + 1) + ' of ' + total);
                // set done steps
                jQuery('li', form).removeClass("done");
                var li_list = navigation.find('li');
                for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                    jQuery(li_list[i]).addClass("done");
                }

                if (current == 1) {
                    form.find('.button-previous').hide();
                } else {
                    form.find('.button-previous').show();
                }

                if (current >= total) {
                    form.find('.button-next').hide();
                    form.find('.button-submit').show();
                } else {
                    form.find('.button-next').show();
                    form.find('.button-submit').hide();
                }

                App.scrollTo($('.page-title'));
            }

            return allowStep;
        },
```

As of yet, I don't know why returning false from inside if statement didn't have same effect.

To make this work, stop the wizard form transferring the user forward, I had to put the return statement outside of any brackets.

Hope this will help others save hours of development it took me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to make sure that a subset of your form fields are valid, ie fields in the current tab.

You can use the valid() plugin method but apply it to a collection of form fields.  As long as the form fields are contained in a form then this will work.  For example to check that all the fields like

```
<form>
<div id="tab1">
 ...form fields here
</div>
...other tabs here
</form>
```

call this

```
var result = $('div#tab1 :input').valid()
```

result will be either 1 or zero, 1 is valid 0 is not

Comment: the problem is not in validation. Validation works great. The problem is that even if the validation fails the wizard still transfers the user to the next tab, and i want to prevent this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am getting the current step and finding all inputs, then I loop through the inputs in the step to determine that each is valid/not valid. Then I return if there was an error.

If I don't use the flag "hadError", and just return valid/not valid, then validation checking stops on each field. There may be more than 1 field invalid but it will only update the error message displayed to the user for the first field it found. So I made the flag so that all the invalid inputs will show the error message, and that is why I loop them and check them seperatly, that I can perform other steps if it is/isn't valid on an individual step basis.

```
                var tabs = $(".tab-pane"); // get the steps
                var currentTab = tabs[index - 1]; //get the current step

                var inputs = $(":input"); // get all the form inputs
                var stepElements = $(currentTab).find(inputs); // get inputs for current step
                var count = stepElements.length; // check that there are inputs
                if (count <= 0) {                // if there are not no reason to loop them 
                    return true;                 // this can be used to perform other action if there are no steps 
                }
                $(stepElements).each(function (idx) {
                    isValid = $(document.forms[0]).validate().element($(this)); // check that the input is valid. This can also be used on a per input basis to perform another action if the field is not valid. 
                    if (!isValid) { hadError = true; } // set our flag if there was an error 

                });

                return !hadError; //return the value of the flag.
```

Note: This only works with inputs and not select. 
You may try to change the line

```
                var inputs = $(":input"); // get all the form inputs
```

To include select

```
                var inputs = $(":input, select"); // get all the form inputs and selects
```

Comment: I use jquery.validate plugin. It does the validation properly. If it fails i, as expected, get false and return it, and nothing after the if statements gets executed, but the wizard still transfers the user to the next tab. My first try is almost exactly the same as in one of the examples for this plugin.

Comment: btw, i dont have forms, i have only 1 form, spread over tabs. I want to validate all fields in current step and let the user fix them all, and only then allow the wizard to move on.